# Clicked Element pass itself to future function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, click

I have an element that has a lot of checkboxes that calls a filter function on change.

However this filter also needs to rely on another filter to accurately present data.

So I have chosen to call filter 2 in filter 1 if filter 2 is active and vice versa.

The problem is passing the clicked elements self to the function eg:

```
$("#filterDiv .paymentList").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', function(PASS ITSELF HERE?) {
  // make Object With acceptable data Values    
}
```

This is a rough fiddle showing the html and the data that have to be passed
https://jsfiddle.net/zv1w6j9u/5/

Comment: You can't pass anything in to an event handler function. You need to select the elements from the DOM when the event fires. It's not 100% clear from your example, but if the element you want is the one which fired the event, you could just use the `this` keyword to reference the element. Also note that your fiddle is broken as it doesn't include jQuery, and you're also using `delegate()` which was deprecated a long time ago. You should be using jQuery 1.12 at least (if you need IE support) better still 3.3.1, and the `on()` method.

Comment: please format your code i want to help but if you cant make it readable then people arent going to want to help

Comment: Please clarify what reference do you need inside your function/callback? What is "PASS ITSELF HERE"? Do you need here access to "#filterDiv .paymentList" or to a clicked checkbox, or something else?

Comment: I have changed it to On and made some code formatting changes
Also the event or element I want to pass is the checkbox input

https://jsfiddle.net/zv1w6j9u/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate is a bit old. You should check out [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). None the less what you are going to have is an [event](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
$("#filterDiv .paymentList").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', function(event) {
 console.log(event.currentTarget);
}
```